# Will Angular 1 die after the release of Angular 2.0?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have just started learning Angular 1 and then someone told me that Angular 2.0 has also been released and hence Angular 1 will die. Most of the concept of Angular 1 has been eliminated in Angular 2.0 such as scope etc. This made me kinda confused and hesitated towards learning Angular 1 and also kinda frustrated because I was totally into learning Angular 1. Angular 2.0 is still in its alpha version. What are your suggestions that should I stop learning Angular 1 and focus on Angular 2.0? and is Angular 1 really going to die in the future? 
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Angular blog about [1 and 2 coexistence](http://angularjs.blogspot.de/2015/08/angular-1-and-angular-2-coexistence.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bear in mind that your question is subjective and Stack Overflow is not the most appropriate place ask it.

There are a few reasons why I would suggest sticking with angular 1.* at this stage:

1. **Documentation**. There are a vast number of online resources dedicated to learning angular 1.*. This is especially useful if you are new to web development.
2. **Mature tooling support**
3. **Mature framework**. Common quirks and "gotchas" have already been discovered by other developers, with answers available here on Stack Overflow.

As a compromise, I would suggest learning angular 1.*, but also using it along with Typescript. There is nothing stopping you from dabbling with angular 2.0 while it is in alpha.

**Update January 2017**
One year on I would definitely recommend that users new to Angular should start learning Angular 2.0 rather than Angular 1.0. I found Angular 2.0 to be much easier to learn and a more pleasant developer experience overall, especially when coupled with `angular-cli`.